# Utilizando For no Python

Tags: python, loop, for, python-3.x

No Python só é possível trabalhar com o 'for' (*loop*) usando uma lista?

Não é possível somente com um número inteiro como nas outras linguagens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, usar uma faixa de dados é a forma idiomática de fazer em Python e não tem o `for` que você conhece  em outras linguagens. O que você pode fazer é usar um `while`, é **quase** igual ao `for` tradicional.

```
x = 0
while x < 3:
    print(x)
    x += 1
```

Forma idiomática:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    print(x)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/w6cvcc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/auhfywst-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/For.py).

Python tem `else` para o `for` que é algo útil e raro em outras linguagens.

Comment: E isso é uma coisa boa: "for" expressa loops que certamente vão terminar (*) enquanto "while" expressa loops que nunca vão terminar. (*) desde que a "lista" não seja um objeto que implemente __iter__(), nesse caso dá pra fazer "for" ser um loop infinito também.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando a resposta, note que você pode utilizar range ou xragne na forma idiomática reportada na resposta anterior.

Utilizar o range pré-aloca em memória todos os itens a serem iterados, o que pode ser um problema se os números são muito grandes. Nestes casos é mais recomendado o uso do xrange, que atua como um gerador, alocando os objetos sob demanda.

Comment: "xrange" só existe no Python 2.x - em Python 3, o range já cria um objeto que não cria dados desnecessários na memória (é o que era o antigo xrange)