# Python, contagem de números pares e impares

Tags: python, funções

Crie um programa em Python que, para uma lista qualquer de valores inteiros, obtém (por meio de funções) e imprime na tela. A quantidade de valores pares e ímpares da lista.

Estou fazendo um programa assim, porém ele não volta as quantidades certas, volta sempre `(1,0)` ou `(0,1)`.

```
    def contaPares(lista):
    pares = 0
    impares = 0
    for lista in range(num):
        if num % 2 == 0:
            pares = pares + 1
        else:
            impares = impares + 1
        return pares, impares





    lista = list()

q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))
while q < 0:
    print('Erro')
    q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))

for c in range(q):
    num = int(input('Valor:'))
    lista.append(num)

print('A quantidade de valores pares e impares são, respectivamente:',contaPares(lista))
```

Comment: Creio que aqui: `for lista in range(num):` deveria ser: `for num in lista:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São dois problemas e ambos acontecem dentro da função `contaPares`.

Um problema é o recuo de seu código.

A maioria das linguagens de programação como *C*, *C++* e *Java* usa chaves `{}` para definir um bloco de código. 
Python usa endentação.

Um bloco de código (corpo de uma função , loop etc.) começa com recuo e termina com a primeira linha sem recuo. A quantidade de recuo depende de você, mas deve ser consistente ao longo desse bloco.

Por causa do recuo o seu código retornava após a primeira iteração:

```
return pares, impares
```

Segundo problema era iteração:

```
for lista in range(num):
```

O correto seria iterar para cada número em sua lista passada como parâmetro:

```
for num in lista:
```

O código funcionando:

```
def contaPares(lista):
    pares = 0
    impares = 0
    for num in lista:
        if (num % 2) == 0:
            pares = pares + 1
        else:
            impares = impares + 1
    return pares, impares





lista = list() 

q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))
while q < 0:
    print('Erro')
    q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))

for c in range(q):
    num = int(input('Valor:'))
    lista.append(num)

print('A quantidade de valores pares e impares são, respectivamente:',contaPares(lista))
```

Link no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/GrimIncomparableWebmaster)

Comment: Salve Augusto, bela resposta! Saberia me informar se há alguma diferença de performance  em fazer `pares +=1` em vez de `pares = pares + 1`? Ou é micro otimização, insignificante pra python?

Comment: @LuizAugusto, Não sei lhe informar. Não tenho condições de afirmar ou negar que `+=` seja apenas açúcar sintático para para um número se auto adicionar a um valor. Acredito que bem formulada de uma boa pergunta aqui na página.

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando de forma errada o comando for:

```
for lista in range(num):
```

Observe que usando o `loop for` desta forma, você está dizendo para percorrer a lista usando range do último `num` inserido pelo seu `input`.

Exemplo:

Caso seu último `num = int(input('Valor:'))` seja `5`, você estará informando erroneamente isto: `for lista in range(5)`.

Seu código correto ficará assim:

```
def contaPares(lista):
    pares = 0
    impares = 0

    for num in lista:
        if (num % 2 == 0):
            pares += 1
        else:
            impares += 1
    return pares, impares

lista = list()

q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))
while q < 0:
    print('Erro')
    q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))

for c in range(q):
    num = int(input('Valor:'))
    lista.append(num)

print('A quantidade de valores pares e impares são, respectivamente:',contaPares(lista))
```

Recomendo a leitura das perguntas:

[Para que serve a função range() em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361275/para-que-serve-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-range-em-python)

[Utilizando For no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165530/utilizando-for-no-python)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um script que contenha uma função que seja capaz de contar a quantidade de números `pares` e `ímpares` de uma determinada lista.

Devido ao fato de existir alguns erros no seu código, decidi elaborar o seguinte código:

```
def pares_impares(lis):

    cont_par = cont_impar = 0
    for item in lis:
        if item % 2 == 0:
            cont_par += 1
        else:
            cont_impar += 1
    return cont_par, cont_impar


valores = list(map(int, input('Digite todos os valores: ').split()))

cont_pares, cont_impares = pares_impares(valores)

print(f'\033[32mA quantidade de números pares é: {cont_pares}')
print(f'A quantidade de números ímpares é: {cont_impares}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite todos os valores:`. Neste momento devemos digitar **todos** os valores, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

Após pressionarmos `enter` será montada uma lista contendo todos os valores e enviada para a função `pares_impares`. Chegando lá, a respectiva lista é percorrida pelo laço de repetição `for`, ao mesmo tempo que cada valor da respectiva interação é verificado se é `par` ou `impar`. Caso o referido valor seja `par`, sua quantidade é acumulada na variável `cont_par` e, caso o referido valor seja `ímpar`, sua quantidade é acumulada na variável `cont_impar`.

Ao final das operações é exibida a quantidade de valores `pares` e `ímpares`.

**Exemplo de execução do script**

Imagine que desejamos inserir os seguintes valores: `1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5`. Então, quando executarmos o script e recebermos a mensagem: `Digite todos os valores`, devemos digitar o seguinte...

```
1 9 2 8 3 7 4 6 5
```

... e pressionar `enter`.

A partir desse momento o script irá realizar as operações descritas anteriormente e nos exibirá o seguinte resultado:

```
A quantidade de números pares é: 4
A quantidade de números ímpares é: 5
```

**Observação**

O tamanho da lista é indefinido, isto é, se você quiser criar uma lista com **3** valores, basta digitar os três valores e pressionar enter. Caso deseje criar uma lista com **20** valores, basta digitar vinte valores e pressionar enter.