# Python contagem por função, BASICO

Tags: python

Crie um programa em Python que, para uma lista qualquer de valores inteiros, obtém (por meio de funções) e imprime na tela, a quantidade de valores positivos, nulos e negativos da lista.

Minha duvida é fazer essa contagens por funções, sempre acaba voltando um valor errado o somente 1.

```
def contaPositivo(lista):
    positivo = 0
    for num in lista:
        if num >0:
            positivo = positivo + 1
        return positivo

def contaNegativo(lista):
    negativo = 0
    for num in lista:
        if num < 0:
            negativo = negativo + 1
        return negativo

lista = list()
q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))
while q < 0:
    print('Erro')
    q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))

for c in range(q):
    num = int(input('Valor:'))
    lista.append(num)
```

Comment: Milton, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/421847/edit) a pergunta e coloque seu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milton, conforme esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/421842/110782) preste atenção na indentação!

Você está colocando o `return` no mesmo nível de indentação do `if` dentro das funções `contaPositivo` e `contaNegativo`, por isso está retornando valores errôneos.

Observe:

```
def contaPositivo(lista):
    positivo = 0
    for num in lista:
        if num >0:
            positivo = positivo + 1
        return positivo #este return deveria estar no mesmo nível do loop for
                                  #e não no nível do if
```

Seu código correto ficará assim:

```
def contaPositivo(lista):
    positivo = 0
    for num in lista:
        if num > 0:
            positivo = positivo + 1
    return positivo #indentação arrumada.

def contaNegativo(lista):
    negativo = 0
    for num in lista:
        if num < 0:
            negativo = negativo + 1
    return negativo #indentação arrumada

lista = list()
q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))
while q < 0:
    print('Erro')
    q = int(input('Quantos valores haverá na lista ?'))

for c in range(q):
    num = int(input('Valor:'))
    lista.append(num)
print("valores positivos", contaPositivo(lista))
print("valores negativos", contaNegativo(lista))
```

Recomendo a leitura:

[INDENTAÇÃO DO CÓDIGO PYTHON](http://excript.com/python/indentacao-python.html)